# Visual studio 2017 flatten class hierarchy in watch

Tags: visual-studio-2017, watch

Is there a way to indicate to Visual Studio 2017 that I want to view my objects in the Watch window like before: not flatten?

For an unknown reason, in a Watch if I drag and drop an object that inherits from a base object, all the properties and variables of the object and its base are represented on the same level.

Thanks.

Comment: Does anyone has an idea?